# How does chain of includes function in C++?

Tags: c++, include, dependencies

- In my `first.cpp` I put `#include second.h`.
  As a consequence `first.cpp` sees the content of `second.cpp`.
- In `second.cpp` I put `#include third.h`.

My question is: will `first.cpp` see the content of the `third.cpp`?

**ADDED**

I thought that if I include second.h I will be able to use functions declared in second.h and described (defined, written) in the second.cpp. In this sense the content of the second.cpp becomes available to the first.cpp

Comment: Why would `first.cpp` see the contents of `second.cpp`?

Comment: `first.cpp` will "see" whatever you've put in `second.h`, nothing more or less.

Answer (score 3):

When using `#include` the actual file content of that file appears as part of the input for the compiler. This means that `first.cpp` will appear to the compiler as if it has `second.h` and `third.h` inside it. The source code in `second.cpp` and `third.cpp` are separate files [1], that need to be compiled separately, and they are all combined at the linking stage at the end of compilation.

[1] unless `second.h` contains `#include "second.cpp"`or something to that effect - this is not typically how to do this, however, so I'm going to ignore that option.

Answer (score 2):

You can think about `#include` as a simple text insert. But if you include `second.h` you "see" `second.h` and not `second.cpp`.

Comment: I thought that if I include `second.h` I will be able to use functions declared in `second.h` and described (defined, written) in the `second.cpp`. In this sense the content of the `second.cpp` becomes available to the `first.cpp`

Comment: @Roman not the content, but declarations. It means first.cpp sees functions (because they are declared in .h file), but it actually doesn't care about implementations (which usually tend to be in .cpp files).

Answer (score 1):

With a concrete example

```
//second.h
#ifndef SECOND_INCLUDED
#define SECOND_INCLUDED

void foo();

#endif
```

```
//first.cpp
#include second.h

void bar()
{
    foo();//ok 
}

void no_good()
{
    wibble();//not ok - can't see declaration from here
}
```

```
//third.h
#ifndef THIRD_INCLUDED
#define THIRD_INCLUDED

void wibble();

#endif
```

```
//second.cpp
#include second.h
#include third.h

void foo()
{
    wibble();//ok in second.cpp since this includes third.h
}
```

The cpp file that includes a header file sees what's in the header file, not in other source files that include the header.

Answer (score 0):

first.cpp will see the constent of third.h (and you will be able to use in first.cpp functions declared in third.h and defined in third.cpp). Suppose, you have in your test.h:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
```

and in your test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl; 
}
```

As you see, `cout` declared in `<iostream>` is visible in test.cpp.

Comment: Are you sure that won't compile?

Comment: It does not compile like that: `g++ test.cpp -o test`

Comment: @doctorlove: It does compile! # was missing in "test.h".